# Spring Rest Template is not returning the data

Tags: java, spring, junit, resttemplate

I am trying to write an integration test for my spring application, I have an api which insert some default data, I run call this api after my test gets initialized

```
@PostConstruct
public void inti() {
    ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.getForEntity("/api/default", String.class);
    assertEquals("Default values are not inserted successfully", "lala", response.getBody());
}
```

This passed and I can see in the database default values.

In my test I try to fetch some data but the returned data is 0 although I tested the api manually and its working

```
@Test
public void shouldReturnDeliveryNotes() {
    ResponseEntity<PagedResources<DeliveryNote>> allDeliveryNotes = restTemplate.exchange("/api/deliverynotes/all?start=0&length=1000",HttpMethod.GET,null,  new ParameterizedTypeReference<PagedResources<DeliveryNote>>() {});
    assertNotEquals("Should have default delivery notes", 0, allDeliveryNotes.getBody().getContent().size());   
}
```

I put some log in the api to see the returned data size and I see the returned data when the test is run is correct which means my test is hitting the right api and the api fetch the data.

```
@GetMapping("/all")
public ResponseEntity<Page<DeliveryNoteDTO>> getAllDeliveryNote(@RequestParam(value = "start", required = false) int start, @RequestParam(value ="length", required = false) int length) {
    Pageable pageable = new OffsetBasedPageRequest(start, (length ==0? Integer.MAX_VALUE: length));
    List<DeliveryNote> page = this.deliveryNoteService.getAllDeliverNotes();
    List<DeliveryNoteDTO> dtoList =page.stream().map(post -> convertToDto(post)).collect(Collectors.toList());
    Page<DeliveryNoteDTO> pageDto = new PageImpl<>(dtoList, pageable, dtoList.size());
    System.out.println("size = "+pageDto.getNumberOfElements());
    return new ResponseEntity<Page<DeliveryNoteDTO>>(pageDto,HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

Any help is appreciated

Comment: I'm a little rusty on restTemplate, but i would try to do the same thing returning just a String or List of Strings, and be sure it works for that.  This will tell you if the problem is with the objects not behaving like POJOS for whatever reason, or if it's the rest template that it the problem.

Comment: In your getAllDleveriyNote you return Paged<DeliveryNoteDTO> but in your test looking for PagedResources<DeliveryNote>. Is this intended?

Comment: @SeanCarroll I needed to serialize it in a resource with default constructor, unfortunatly page and pageImpl does not have that , though I fixed my issue with extending PageImpl and define a new constructor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is I am returning Page while in my restTemplate I am expecting PagedResources, it would make sense to just return page but I need a concrete class , I would use PageImpl but the problem is that PageImple does not have a default constructor which RestTemplate use to map the response, so What I did I created a new class and extended the PageImpl just as mentioned in the accepted answer of this question

[Spring RestTemplate with paginated API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34647303/spring-resttemplate-with-paginated-api)