# Ho to Implement Pagination while calling external API in SpringBoot

Tags: java, spring-boot, pagination

My microservice call 2  external API and merges their response and send back data two the client.

I want to implement pagination of the data recieve from 2 API and send back to client.

Can Anyone help me out how to achieve this in Spring Boot.

Comment: Are you storing the data from External API some where to paginate it?

Comment: pls check if the apis you are calling are paginated, they should be. If they are paginated , then while calling you can follow this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34647303/spring-resttemplate-with-paginated-api?noredirect=1&lq=1 to retrieve results and then send them back to client.

Comment: It depends on the external API that you deal with! if it's provided pagination API or not ,