# Consume a service with restTemplate

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-rest

In a spring boot (1.4.1) application, i try to consume a rest template

```
 @GetMapping(value = "/visits")
    public ResponseEntity<CustomPageImpl<VisitDto>> getVisits(Pageable pageRequest) {
          return restTemplate.getForEntity("", new TypeReference<CustomPageImpl<VisitDto>>() {});
    }
```

like the answer of Ali Dehghani in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34099559/how-to-consume-pageentity-response-using-spring-resttemplate), i create a CustomPageImpl

about TypeReference, import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.type.TypeReference;

i get this message

```
no suitable method found for getForEntity(String,<anonymous TypeReference<CustomPageImpl<VisitDto>>>)
    method RestTemplate.<T#1>getForEntity(String,Class<T#1>,Object...) is not applicable
      (cannot infer type-variable(s) T#1
        (argument mismatch; <anonymous TypeReference<CustomPageImpl<VisitDto>>> cannot be converted to Class<T#1>))
    method RestTemplate.<T#2>getForEntity(String,Class<T#2>,Map<String,?>) is not applicable
      (cannot infer type-variable(s) T#2
        (actual and formal argument lists differ in length))
    method RestTemplate.<T#3>getForEntity(URI,Class<T#3>) is not applicable
      (cannot infer type-variable(s) T#3
        (argument mismatch; String cannot be converted to URI))
  where T#1,T#2,T#3 are type-variables:
    T#1 extends Object declared in method <T#1>getForEntity(String,Class<T#1>,Object...)
    T#2 extends Object declared in method <T#2>getForEntity(String,Class<T#2>,Map<String,?>)
    T#3 extends Object declared in method <T#3>getForEntity(URI,Class<T#3>)
```

With

```
ResponseEntity<CustomPageImpl<VisitDto>> response = restTemplate.getForEntity(URI.create("url"), new TypeReference<ResponseEntity<CustomPageImpl<VisitDto>>>() {});
```

get same error

Answer (score -1):

try  [getForEntity(URI url,Class responseType)](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/client/RestTemplate.html#getForEntity-java.net.URI-java.lang.Class-)

```
    @GetMapping(value = "/visits")
        public ResponseEntity<CustomPageImpl<VisitDto>> getVisits(Pageable pageRequest) {
              ResponseEntity<CustomPageImpl<VisitDto>> response = restTemplate.getForEntity(Uri.parse("url"), new TypeReference<CustomPageImpl<VisitDto>>() {});
return response;
        }
```

Comment: Seem URI javax.net, parse don't exist it's parser and it's private so it's create... but get same error