# Rest API Page Deserialization with RestClient in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest

Our Consumed REST APIs are returning results in Pages. Here is an example:

Event Bean class:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@JsonIgnoreProperties
public class Event implements Serializable {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -7613296461448310227L;

    private String name;
    private String id;
    private String type;
    
}
```

EventList Bean class:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@JsonIgnoreProperties
public class EventList {

    @JsonProperty("events")
    private List<Event> events = null;
}
```

Response Bean class:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@JsonIgnoreProperties
public class EventResponse {

    @JsonProperty("_embedded")
    private EventList responseList = null;
}
```

Logic to call Rest API with RestTemplate:

```
ParameterizedTypeReference<RestResponsePage<Event>> responseType = new ParameterizedTypeReference<RestResponsePage<Event>>() {
            };

            ResponseEntity<RestResponsePage<Event>> response = this.restTlsTemplate
                    .exchange(this.url, HttpMethod.GET, entity, responseType);

            RestResponsePage<Event> eventsResources = response.getBody();

            Collection<Event> eventsCollection = eventsResources.getContent();
```

RestResponsePage class:

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class RestResponsePage<T> extends PageImpl<T> {
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -5317908588846766606L;

    @JsonCreator(mode = JsonCreator.Mode.PROPERTIES)
    public RestResponsePage(@JsonProperty("content") List<T> content,
                            @JsonProperty("number") int number,
                            @JsonProperty("size") int size,
                            @JsonProperty("totalElements") Long totalElements,
                            @JsonProperty("pageable") JsonNode pageable,
                            @JsonProperty("last") boolean last,
                            @JsonProperty("totalPages") int totalPages,
                            @JsonProperty("sort") JsonNode sort,
                            @JsonProperty("first") boolean first,
                            @JsonProperty("numberOfElements") int numberOfElements) {

        super(content, PageRequest.of(number, size), totalElements);
    }

    public RestResponsePage(List<T> content, Pageable pageable, long total) {
        super(content, pageable, total);
    }

    public RestResponsePage(List<T> content) {
        super(content);
    }

    public RestResponsePage() {
        super(new ArrayList<>());
    }
}
```

It throwing an exception when trying with above:

`Error = JSON conversion problem: Cannot construct instance of` *.*.*..RestResponsePage`, problem: Page size must not be less than one!; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.ValueInstantiationException: Cannot construct instance of`* .*.*..RestResponsePage`, problem: Page size must not be less than one! at [Source: (PushbackInputStream); line: 81, column: 1] | JSON conversion problem: Cannot construct instance of` *.*.*..RestResponsePage`, problem: Page size must not be less than one!; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.ValueInstantiationException: Cannot construct instance of`* .*.*..RestResponsePage`, problem: Page size must not be less than one! at [Source: (PushbackInputStream); line: 81, column: 1]`

I have seen some posts similar to this issue but I has also trying the same and it didn't working for me. So can anyone please help me on this as i am not getting the issue and also I am new to this Page Deserialization with Rest Client.

Comment: duplicate of this:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56129912/resttemplate-mapping-page-page-size-must-not-be-less-than-one

Comment: @Krishna were you able to fix the issue? Even I'm also getting the issue.