# Spring boot: testing paged results using TestRestTemplate

Tags: java, spring, integration-testing, spring-restcontroller, spring-rest

I have a resource A that have a controller containing an endpoint for retrieving paged A items:

```
      public ResponseEntity getAllAs(
      @PageableDefault(size = 25, value = 0) Pageable pageable) {
        Page<A> pagedAs = .....
        return ResponseEntity.ok(pagedAs);
  }
```

When I have tried to create an integration test and calling  this endpoint using TestRestTemplate, I got a problem because a `Page` object cannot be instantiated.

Here is the call:

```
    ResponseEntity<Page> response =  template.getForEntity("/api/as,
            Page.class );
```

And here is the exception:

```
  com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: Cannot construct instance of `org.springframework.data.domain.Page` (no Creators, like default construct, exist): abstract types either need to be mapped to concrete types, have custom deserializer, or contain additional type information
 at [Source: (PushbackInputStream); line: 1, column: 1]
```

I guess it is a normal regarding the fact that `Page` cannot be instantiated but this constrains the testability when using spring boot paginated results.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to consume Page<Entity> response using Spring RestTemplate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34099559/how-to-consume-pageentity-response-using-spring-resttemplate)

Comment: @jhyot in the chosen answer of that question the last comment says "I still gives me the error"

Comment: that's because the commenter still uses an abstract class inside his concrete one. The accepted example to my linked question should work.

Answer (score 0):

Make changes in the response of the controller from `Page<T>` to `List<T>`.

```
public ResponseEntity getAllAs(
       @PageableDefault(size = 25, value = 0) Pageable pageable) {
       Page < A > pagedAs = .....
       return ResponseEntity.ok(pagedAs);
   }
```

Then convert where you are consuming the API from List to Page

```
Page<T> page = new PageImpl<>(list);
```