# Json Parsing and assign to DTO

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, maven, jsonparser

Issue while parsing JSON into DTO.

JSON response is :

```
{
  "content": [
    {
      "id": 350,
      "reg": "FA-2001",
      "Email": "abc@gmail.in",
      "Mobile": "+9192000000",
      "Name": "dr kumar",
      "Ip": "0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1",
      "Datetime": "2022-10-20T13:50:49",
    }
  ],
  "pageable": {
    "sort": {
      "unsorted": false,
      "sorted": true,
      "empty": false
    },
    "pageNumber": 0,
    "pageSize": 20,
    "offset": 0,
    "paged": true,
    "unpaged": false
  },
  "last": true,
  "totalPages": 1,
  "totalElements": 1,
  "first": true,
  "sort": {
    "unsorted": false,
    "sorted": true,
    "empty": false
  },
  "numberOfElements": 1,
  "size": 20,
  "number": 0,
  "empty": false
}
```

DTO

```
@Data
public class OtherResponse {
    @JsonProperty(value = "content")
    private Map content;
}
```

Getting

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot deserialize value of type java.util.LinkedHashMap<java.lang.Object,java.lang.Object> from Array value (token JsonToken.START_ARRAY)
```

Please suggest how to get value in Map or some other object
My main focus is to send specific key value pair in response.

Comment: "Getting json parsing error" - Show us the error message / stacktrace

Comment: not parsing but de serialize error
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot deserialize value of type `java.util.LinkedHashMap<java.lang.Object,java.lang.Object>` from Array value (token `JsonToken.START_ARRAY`)

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the full stack trace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your json String, the `content` is a List. what you can do is to update the `OtherResponse` accordingly:

```
@Data
public class OtherResponse {
    @JsonProperty(value = "content")
    private List<Map<String, String>> content;

    private Pageable pageable;
}
```

Or even define a dedicated class for it:

```
@Data
public class OtherResponse {
    @JsonProperty(value = "content")
    private List<Person> content;

    private Pageable pageable;
}
```

PS: updated answer and added the Pageable field. I am using here the Pageable interface imported from `org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable`

Comment: thank you @Emanuel it's working for me i am getting 

{
    "content": [
        {
            "id": "350",
            "registrationNo": "FQ-123",
            "Email": "test1@gmail.in"
        }
    ]
}

i just need to remove map name from the json output and want like this 

{
    "data": [
        {
            "id": "350",
            "registrationNo": "FQ-123",
            "Email": "test1@gmail.in"
        }
    ]
}

Comment: i have created dedicated class to parse the json data, Now i need one more help i want to save **pageable** key into DTO dedicated class my json is 

`{
  "data": [
    {
      "id": 350,
      "registrationNo": "FA-01",
      "applicantEmail": "test@nn.kk",
      "applicantMobile": "9999999998",
    }
  ],
  "pageable": {
    "sort": {
      "unsorted": false,
      "sorted": true,
      "empty": false
    },
    "pageNumber": 0,
    "pageSize": 20,
    "offset": 0,
    "paged": true,
    "unpaged": false
  }
}`

Comment: i have updated the initial answer, take a look :)

Comment: getting exception 'com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: Cannot construct instance of 
`org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable (no Creators, like default constructor, exist): abstract types either need to be mapped to concrete types, have custom deserializer, or contain additional type information`

Comment: you can try to fix this as described here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52490399/spring-boot-page-deserialization-pageimpl-no-constructor
or you can create your own pageable implementation